# how can I implement the onProgressUpdate method in this AsynTask Class

Tags: android, android-studio, android-asynctask

I'm working on a network scanner, and for that I'm sending the scan to the background using an AsyncTask class. But I'm having problems implementing the onProgressUpdate() method. I'm passing an ArrayList of type string to the TaskScanNetwork class. This array will have a list of all life host on network. Any help appreciated. Thanks

```
package com.example.android.droidscanner;

import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.lang.reflect.Array;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button btnRead;
    Button btnScan;
    TextView textResult;

    ListView listViewNode;
    ArrayList<Node> listNote;
    ArrayList<String> listNetwork;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        btnRead = (Button)findViewById(R.id.readhost);
        btnScan = (Button) findViewById(R.id.readnet);
        textResult = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.result);

        listViewNode = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.nodelist);
        listNote = new ArrayList<>();
        listNetwork = new ArrayList<>();

        //initidating adapter for host only
        ArrayAdapter<Node> adapterHost = new ArrayAdapter<Node>(
                MainActivity.this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                listNote);
        listViewNode.setAdapter(adapterHost);

        //initiating adapter for network scan
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapterNetwork = new ArrayAdapter(
                MainActivity.this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                listNetwork);
        listViewNode.setAdapter(adapterNetwork);


        btnRead.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                new TaskReadAddresses(listNote, listViewNode).execute();
            }
        });

        btnRead.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                new TaskScanNetwork(listNetwork, listViewNode).execute();
            }
        });
    }


    private class TaskReadAddresses extends AsyncTask<Void, Node, Void> {

        ArrayList<Node> array;
        ListView listView;

        TaskReadAddresses(ArrayList<Node> array, ListView v){
            listView = v;
            this.array = array;
            array.clear();
            textResult.setText("querying...");
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            readAddresses();
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
            textResult.setText("Done");
        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Node... values) {
            listNote.add(values[0]);
            ((ArrayAdapter)(listView.getAdapter())).notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        private void readAddresses() {
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = null;

            try {
                bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("/proc/net/arp"));

                String line;
                while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                    String[] splitted = line.split(" +");
                    if (splitted != null && splitted.length >= 4) {
                        String ip = splitted[0];
                        String mac = splitted[3];
                        if (mac.matches("..:..:..:..:..:..")) {
                            Node thisNode = new Node(ip, mac);
                            publishProgress(thisNode);
                        }
                    }
                }

            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally{
                try {
                    bufferedReader.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    /*
    * Asynctask to scan the network
    * */
    private class TaskScanNetwork extends AsyncTask<Void, ArrayList<String>, Void> {

        String network;
        ListView listView;
        String lowBoundIp;
        ArrayList<String> allNetwork;

        TaskScanNetwork(ArrayList<String> array, ListView v){
            listView = v;
            allNetwork = array;
            textResult.setText("Scanning...");
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            scanNetwork();
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
            textResult.setText("Done");
        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(ArrayList<String>... values) {
            allNetwork.add(values);
            ((ArrayAdapter)(listView.getAdapter())).notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        private void scanNetwork() {
            try {
                InetAddress localHost = InetAddress.getLocalHost();
                lowBoundIp = localHost.getHostAddress();
                int lastDot = lowBoundIp.lastIndexOf(".");
                String host = lowBoundIp.substring(0, lastDot);
                Process ping;
                for(int i = 1; i < 255; i++) {
                    host = host + "." + Integer.toString(i);
                    try {
                        ping = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("ping -n 1 " + host);
                        int returnVal = ping.waitFor();
                        if(returnVal == 0) {
                            publishProgress(allNetwork);
                        }
                    }
                    catch(Exception ex) {
                        ex.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }  catch (UnknownHostException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what is exactly your problem?

Comment: can't add the host to the arraylist.... on the doInBackground() method.

Comment: I think you should rewrite your question an make it more clear. I don't understand what do you want to achieve with the `ArrayList`, suppose you want to store there all the host you get from the net and then return that?